# Make <div> visible only in @media print or when Ctrl+P is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a HTML division `div` that is visible only when print is given i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is pressed and not visible in the normal page view

...

I tried the below method. But it is not working.

Is there anybody who know about it

```css
@media print {
            
      .print_only {
          display: block;
          visibility: visible;
      }
}
```

```html
<div class="print_only" style="visibility:hidden; display:none"> THIS IS THE MOST DIFFICULT QUESTION OF THE CENTURY </div>
```

Comment: Also add your class outside your `@media print` section with `display:none;` like `.print_only {display: none;}` to hide your division when not printing

Comment: Adding the style inside the html tag, will not show it when printing, the tag html will over-ride the css html

Comment: Yes dude ..... It works with your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using this method .... Thank you all ... Especially @pokeybit

```css
.print_only {
            display: none;
        }
    
        @media print {
            
            
            .print_only {
                display: block;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            
            body * {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            #print_area, #print_area * {
                visibility: visible;
            }
            #print_area {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: -100px;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is how I solved my own problem with all your helping codes

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't show because the inline style `display:none` overrides the style specified for the class `print_only`. See [this](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) excellent article for details on CSS specificity.

You need to put

```
.print_only {
     display: none; 
}
```

in your CSS (outside the `@media print` block) and remove the inline style from the HTML.

Comment: I have added the answer below ..... Have a look..Be sure to visit my website http://mbitlabs.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to put !important after the display: block;. The inline style overwrite the style on the class. You can also do this:

```
.print_only {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope it helps you!